# Don't understand, IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, filter, distance

My task is to remove longitude and latitude coordinates if the distance between points are within a specific distance (5km or 10km or 30km). This is for modeling purposes and avoid clustering of points. I am using haversine equation to measure distance.

Below is my initial code:

```
load the geometry record from points,  
then convert it to an array, 
compare each coordinate pairs and measure distance. 
After that, remove the longitude and latitude pairs that are   
close to each other,
```

but got stuck on this step.

What I am planning is to update the item list of coordinate pairs and iterate again using new set of coordinate pairs.

Running the below script gives me this error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

It seems that the index in the iteration is not updating. It still getting the index during the first pass.

```
import math, easygui, shapefile, itertools, os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filepath = easygui.fileopenbox()

input_dist = int(raw_input("Distance Filter Value?: "))
input_crop = raw_input("what crop?: ")

directory = os.path.split(filepath)[0]

def dist_haversine(shp,input_dist,input_crop):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """

    r = shapefile.Reader(shp)
    idx = np.arange(len(r.records()))
    coordinates = []
    for i in idx:
        geom = r.shape(i)
        coordinates.append(geom.points[0])    

    acoords = np.array(coordinates)

    for r,n in itertools.izip(acoords[:,0],acoords[:,1]):

        coordinates_ = []

        for i,j in itertools.izip(acoords[:,0],acoords[:,1]):

            lon1=r
            lat1=n
            lon2=i
            lat2=j

            lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(math.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

            # haversine formula
            dlon = lon2 - lon1 
            dlat = lat2 - lat1 
            a = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon/2)**2
            c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a)) 
            km = c*6371 #/1000.0

            if km > input_dist:
                coordinates_.append([i,j])

        coordinates[:] = coordinates_
        acoords = np.array(coordinates)

    df_coords_ = pd.DataFrame(coordinates).drop_duplicates().values
    df_coords = pd.DataFrame(df_coords_, columns=['Lon','Lat'])

    df_coords.insert(0, 'Crop', input_crop)  

    return df_coords.to_csv(os.path.split(directory)[0] + "\\" + "%s_distFilter_%skm.csv" % (input_crop, input_dist), sep=",", index=None)
```

> **Traceback**
>
> > ```
> > File "<ipython-input-3-8e88eba2ab54>", line 1,  in <module>  
> >   dist_haversine(filepath,input_dist,input_crop)
> > File "<ipython-input-2-d43a1f1da26a>", line 20, in 
> >   dist_haversine  
> >     for i,j in itertools.izip(acoords[:,0],acoords[:,1]):  
> > IndexError: too many indices for array
> > ```

Comment: Hi, please post the full exception. Also it might help to "boil down" the issue and add some sample data. It seems the question isn't really about coordinates but rather a NumPy array.

Comment: Hi, here is the complete error message: Traceback (most recent call last): /n File "<ipython-input-3-8e88eba2ab54>", line 1, in <module>
    dist_haversine(filepath,input_dist,input_crop) /n File "<ipython-input-2-d43a1f1da26a>", line 20, in dist_haversine
    for i,j in itertools.izip(acoords[:,0],acoords[:,1]): /n  IndexError: too many indices for array /n I uploaded the file in Dropbox here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2s25tlkzbif3d54/sample_rice.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: Any workaround?

Comment: Maybe someone would be willing to help YOU, if you would bother to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is the initial solution that I used to filter points. Its working, and a bit fast for a 1,000 - 3,000 points dataset. However, tried filtering 50,000 points, it took 2.5 - 3 hours to finish.

```
def dist_haversine(filepath,input_dist,input_crop):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """

    r = shapefile.Reader(filepath)
    idx = np.arange(len(r.records()))
    coordinates = []
    for i in idx:
        geom = r.shape(i)
        coordinates.append(geom.points[0])       

    acoords = np.array(coordinates)

    index = []        
    for r,n,l in itertools.izip(acoords[:,0],acoords[:,1],idx):
        if l in index:
            continue
        else:
            for i,j,k in itertools.izip(acoords[:,0],acoords[:,1], idx):
                if k in index:
                    continue

                else:

                    lon1=r
                    lat1=n
                    lon2=i
                    lat2=j

                    coord_check = ((lon1 == lon2) & (lat1 == lat2))*1

                    if coord_check == 1:
                        continue

                    else:
                        lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(math.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

                        # haversine formula
                        dlon = lon2 - lon1 
                        dlat = lat2 - lat1 
                        a = math.sin(dlat/2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon/2)**2
                        c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a)) 
                        km = c*6371 #/1000.0

                    if km < input_dist:
                        if k in index:
                            continue
                        else:
                            index.append(k)

    filterList = [i for j, i in enumerate(coordinates) if j not in index]

    df_coords = pd.DataFrame(filterList, columns=['Lon','Lat'])

    df_coords.insert(0, 'Crop', input_crop)  

    return df_coords.to_csv(directory + "\\" + "%s_distFilter_%skm.csv" % (input_crop, input_dist), sep=",", index=None)
```